# How do I create an apple developers account for my child

Tags: accounts

I would like to create an apple developers account for my child who has a child account .When I try to sign-in with his account, it gives me an error saying 'Sorry, you cannot access this page'.

Comment: What kind of error? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting questions. This question is very hard to understand what you are asking because of lack of detail.

Comment: Ok, Thank You Charlie Fish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong but I believe there is an age restriction on an Apple Developers Account. You also shouldn't be creating a developer account for someone else which you don't have control for. Overall definitely what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: **Thank You** for your advice!